# cannot open display: localhost:0.0

Tags: bash, graphics, windows, firefox

I'm trying to get a program called "Freesurfer" set up with ubuntu on windows 10 using bash.

The program works fine but I need to use something called "Freeview" which is a graphical application within the program. For this they recommend using "Xming server" which I have downloaded.

I've read that I type: `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` inside the ubuntu terminal and I've done so but when I try to start any graphical application be it freeview or firefox, I simply get the error in the title.

I'm not sure where the problem is and I've really tried to figure it out but to no avail. I'm a complete novice in Ubuntu so bear with me.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck while editing the ssh config file in the ubuntu console window...I'm not sure how to exit it after I've added the lines? I want to save and exit.

Comment: Which editor did you use to edit?

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't realize I was using one at all, I was using nano. But I did go through some of the answers of the thread and one states: Just set DISPLAY and you're good to go (for xming and VcXsrv anyways)

This seems to be what I'm supposed to do according to: http://christopher5106.github.io/admin/2018/02/02/configure-windows-10-for-ubuntu.html

But it still says "0 clients connected" on xming after writing this command.